# Como saber si un usuario está autenticado usando asp.net Identity

Tags: session, identity

Utilizando el framework **Identity**, como saber si el usuario No está auntenticado aún, y enviarlo a la página de Login.
Antes yo lo hacía de la siguiente manera:

```
if (Session["Num_Cliente"] == null)
Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

Pero no sé si utilizando Identity en un proyecto **WebForm** sea conviniente o lo suficiente seguro o lo suficiente óptimo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta que buscas, muy resumidamente, creo que es esta o más o menos:

```
bool isAuth = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

if(!isAuth) return View("Login"); 

  return View("AccessAuthorized");
```

Comment: Podrias explicar mas como llegaste a esta respuesta, te invito a leer [answer]

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas declarar el atributo [Authorize] encima de un controlador o acción específica dentro de tu controlador. Automáticamente cuando el usuario intente acceder al controlador o a la acción que contenga el atributo [Authorize], si este no esta autenticado, será redirigido al login automáticamente. Este atributo tambien admite parámetros con el fin de definir reglas de authorización para determinados usuarios dependiendo del roll al que pertenece. Sobre Identity debes saber que es el sistema de membresía por defecto para el Framework Asp.Net y el recomendado Microsoft para incorporar en tu proyecto, al igual que lo suficiente seguro y óptimo.

Comment: hace 4 dias estaba buscando la respuesta! gracias Vicente Almea!!!!!!